# AngularJS - Service talking to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks

Angular JS has pretty cool feature of two-way binding which allows controller data to automatically get updated when view changes (or vice-versa).
Today we can have controllers dependent on services.
Is it possible for services to depend on controller?
For e.g. if a service wants to fetch certain data from a controller on it's own will, is it possible?

Also, is it possible to extend the scope of ng-model variable to pass to the service (along with controller) as variable, which keeps in sync automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Both of those scenarios sound like a pretty terrible idea. Respect your application's state. Don't try to pass it around everywhere. "Yeah, yeah, but your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn't stop to think if they should." - Jeff Goldblum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign multiple variables to the same object , each is a reference to the same object.

Following is for demonstration. This may not be preferred approach depending on use case

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.mainModel = MyService.myObject;
})

app.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.otherModel = MyService.myObject;
})

app.factory('MyService', function() {
  return {
    myObject: {
      name: 'test'
    }
  }
});
```

Both of the following inputs will show the same value

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     Name:<input ng-model="mainModel.name">
</div>
<div ng-controller="OtherCtrl">
     Name:<input ng-model="otherModel.name">
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0iozvWHdO9uZJHaVkb9?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Will the change be reflected immediately in the view if it changes in the service?

Comment: as long as you don't break the object reference. If you reassign `myObject` in service it would break it...but changing value of `myObject.name` won't. Easy enough for you to create another method to try it yourself

Comment: and if you stop and think about that question, each controller is already doing that when you type in the input

Comment: Tried it on localhost, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: no reason it shouldn't the demo works fine